# How to include variable and text in MsgBox in MS ACCESS and VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created a variable "CurrentUserID" as a String in a module. This variable identifies which user has logged in and out.

In my current Message Box, I have MsgBox (CurrentUserID). This just brings a pop up of the name of the user which has logged in. How do I add a message in it whilst having the "CurrentUserID" variable.

For example If I logged in as bob. The message will say "bob" (through CurrentUserID). How can I add some text so it could be "redirecting to details bob"

Thank you

Comment: MsgBox "redirecting to details " & CurrentUserID

Comment: Concatenation. `MsgBox "Redirecting to details " & CurrentUserID` or maybe `MsgBox "Redirecting details to " & CurrentUserID`

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks. Just one question how would I space the user out. The message comes up as Redirecting to personal detailsbob"

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the *string concatenation operator*, `&`.

```
MsgBox "Redirecting details to " & CurrentUserID
```

If all operands are strings, you can also use the `+` operator to concatenate strings:

```
MsgBox "Redirecting details to " + CurrentUserID
```

But since the `+` operator has other, more obvious purposes (i.e. adding numbers), it's best to stick to the `&` operator, which will implicitly convert its operands into strings if it needs to.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks. Just one question how would I space the user out. The message comes up as Redirecting to personal detailsbob"

Comment: you can use as many concatenations as you want - like this `"bob" & " " & "is at" & " home"` - see how i used spaces?